# Some More Program Logic Assistance Requested

Tags: c#

I have these partial listings of two classes.  A CiscoSwitch object maintains a list of SwitchConnection objects to other switches.  I am trying to write the code that will walk a list of switches and return the switches that have common connections, either to each other or to the same RemoteSwitchName listed in the connection list of the other switches but it might not be in the list of CiscoSwitches I am working with.

for example if I have a list of 3 CiscoSwitch instances named A, B and C.  A and B might be connected to each other.  B and C might not be connected directly to each other but both are connected to D.  A might also be connected to D.   I am comparing the RemoteSwitchName attribute of each switch connection to the switchName property of the other switches in the list and to the RemoteSwitchName property of the other SwitchConnections on the other switches.

I'd prefer to use LINQ rather than a lot of foreach loops if possible.

```
public CiscoSwitch 
{ 
private string _SwitchName = String.Empty
public string switchName{ get{return _SwitchName;} set{_SwitchName=value;} }        
 ...
public List<SwitchConnection> SwitchConnectionList = new List<SwitchConnection>();
...
 }

public class SwitchConnection
    // a switch connection is a connection to another switch
    // a switch connection can have multiple portchannels 
    // a switch connection can exist across multiple VSANs
{ 
   // the name of this switch
   // not needed, deprecated
  //  private string _LocalSwitchName;
  //  public string LocalSwitchName { get { return _LocalSwitchName; } set { _LocalSwitchName = value; } }

    // the name of the switch at the other end of the link
    private string _RemoteSwitchName;
    public string RemoteSwitchName { get { return _RemoteSwitchName; } set { _RemoteSwitchName = value; } }
    private string _RemoteIPAddress;
    public string RemoteIPAddress { get { return _RemoteIPAddress; } set { _RemoteIPAddress = value; } }
    public Dictionary<int, PortChannel> LocalPortChannelList = new Dictionary<int,PortChannel>();
}
```

Comment: You have told us a story and shown us some code. What is the actual question? What have you tried?

Comment: -1: Question title is really bad in addition to missing question part.

Comment: the question is how to do what I want. I thought that was evident in what I posted.  So restated in the form of a question "How can I traverse a list of switches and return the common connections between switches, either to each other or a switch that might not be in the list".   As to what I have tried, I made several attempts at nested foreach loops but I think after reading @radarbob's post I will have to add some more methods to the classes.

Comment: I am attempting to draw a diagram of the network. I don't want to draw every switch.  I want to draw only the switches I have logs for, plus any that sit between the ones I have logs for.

Answer (score 0):

`private string _RemoteSwitchName` should be a reference to an actual object rather than a "disconnected" switch name, I think. Then getting the name is like this:

```
protected SwitchConnection RemoteSwitch;

this.RemoteSwitch.Name;  //need to add "Name" property to the class, of course.
```

This reference will also allow you to traverse through the chain of connections rather easily. This is not mutually exclusive of your idea to query your collection. However finding the "chain" for this given connection will be easier than with LINQ I think.

```
    // in SwitchConnection class
    public List<string> GetAllConnections(List<string> connectionChain) {

    // to start at any given object just pass in a null reference
    if (connectionChain == null) { connectionChain = new List<string>; }

    connectionChain.Add(this.Name);

    if (this.RemoteSwitch !=null) {
       RemoteSwitch.GetAllConnections(connectionChain);
    }

    return connectionChain;
}
```

If you think you are going to have lots of different queries, I'm thinking that a separate class for this will keep your `CiscoSwitch` and `SwitchConnection` classes clean. As you learn/experiment with LINQ your "core classes" won't be continually breaking due to LINQ learning mistakes.

**You'll notice I've not shown any LINQ**.  You'll have to get started on your own. But [start simple and be methodical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx).

Comment: it took several minutes to see where you were going with this.  the RemoteSwichName property could be a reference to an actual switch object. Oh the code above you have "ConnectionSwitch RemoteSwitch" as a property of the SwitchConnection class.  Did you mean RemoteSwitch to be a property of type CiscoSwitch or a property of type SwitchConnection?  I think it makes more sense for it to be a SwitchConnection.

Comment: sorry, I switched Switch and Connection. **I think it makes more sense for it to be a SwitchConnection.** - yes.